# MySQL / MySQLi SELECT with UNIONS no NULLS and ORDERED BY how?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have this....

```
$query = "SELECT {$selections} FROM {$table_1} 
        UNION ALL SELECT {$selections} FROM {$table_2} 
        UNION SELECT {$selections} FROM {$table_3}
        UNION SELECT {$selections} FROM {$table_4}
        ORDER BY FIELD(series, {$seriesOrder}) ";
```

This works great, but what I am now trying to do is exclude values in {$column_7} that have a NULL value on each table, I tried this....

```
$query = "SELECT {$selections} FROM {$table_1} WHERE {$column_7} IS NOT NULL
        UNION ALL SELECT {$selections} FROM {$table_2} WHERE {$column_7} IS NOT NULL
        UNION SELECT {$selections} FROM {$table_3} WHERE {$column_7} IS NOT NULL
        UNION SELECT {$selections} FROM {$table_4} WHERE {$column_7} IS NOT NULL
        ORDER BY FIELD(series, {$seriesOrder})";
```

However, this is not working!
I am obviously missing something, been researching this for a while and can't find the answer need help please...

Comment: What does "not working" mean?

Comment: Not working means not getting any returns on my query, and only 20 items out of 500 have {$column_7} set as NULL, so theoretically I should get 480 results. But I get none. The query is not working!

Comment: @GordonLinoff, got this done I was missing an apostrophe :-)

Comment: . . You should delete the question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I can't delete it, there is no option to delete it! There is certain criteria for deleting questions, and this doesn't meet any of them!

Answer (score -1):

This was fixed by correcting a punctuation/syntax error which was a single missing apostrophe!
WOW!! :-)